# How to make my app publicly downloadable from Google Play Store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

Since it says that you have to be a beta tester in order to download. but how can I make it publicly available for all the users?

also, production release has been rolled out in case anyone wanna ask that. and idk what's the next step that I should do in order to make it publicly available for download.

I tried to google this issue but didn't find any suitable solution please help.

Comment: You can release your app in open testing or production to make it available to all users. You can also limit the number of users to use your app in open testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check which track you have uploaded your `apk/bundle` to:

- Production track - This track is for distributing your project to the market, and to your end users. If you have an `api/bundle` published here then the app will be present on play store for anyone to download.
- Open track - Similar to Closed, but anyone who has opt in beta testing can also download the app.
- Closed track - A more controlled version of internal testing. Users can be requested to join and provide feedback.
- Internal track - Only people whose email is in the testers email list will be able to download the app from this track on play store.

I think you forgot to add your email under testers in either internal/closed/open track.

Comment: thanks for the reply karan but why should I add email under testers  when i've already tested it. now I wanted to make it available publicly. but how can I do that?

Comment: Just submit your build under the production track. It will be available for everyone.